# LeafletJS – Interacting with Maps using JavaScript and Json file

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, leaflet

Hello this is my first time using leafleftJS and I would like to make interaction between the map and json file.
but i have an error so i dont know where is my mistake.

this is my javascript code:

```
  fetch("./assets/js/people.json")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach(person => {
      let content = `<h3>${person.name}</h3><br>${person.phone}`;
      let mark=L.marker([person.lat, person.lng])
      .bindPopup(content)
      .addTo(map);
    });
  }).catch(error => console.error(error));
```

and this is the json file:

```
[
    {
      "lat": 47.50145,
      "lng": 10.12264,
      "name": "Cindy",
      "phone": 0000000000
    },
    {
      "lat": 47.48756,
      "lng": 12.18524,
      "name": "Gaia",
      "phone": 1111111111
    }
  ]
```

using the console log in inspector , each time i click on the marker i get this error and non popup  appear :(

```
VM773 leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at i._updateContent (VM773 leaflet.js:5:91249)
    at i.update (VM773 leaflet.js:5:90254)
    at i.onAdd (VM773 leaflet.js:5:89656)
    at i.onAdd (VM773 leaflet.js:5:92018)
    at i._layerAdd (VM773 leaflet.js:5:63932)
    at i.whenReady (VM773 leaflet.js:5:42041)
    at i.addLayer (VM773 leaflet.js:5:64307)
    at i.openPopup (VM773 leaflet.js:5:94859)
    at i.openPopup (Popup.js:424:14)
    at i._openPopup (Popup.js:499:9)
```

Comment: How are you defining the `map` variable? I've created a simple example, and you can play around with it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q67naL54/). If the rest of your code is essentially different from my example, please post the rest of your code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. when i put the data in the same file with map works fine but when i separate those data from map.js  by creating for example people.js doesnt work.

Comment: Is the error the same? Are you including your people.js before map.js?

Comment: the error showed is only when i try to add  "bindPopup(content)" to the code in order to show the information about the marker.

Comment: What do you get if you log the `content` to the console? For example, [like this](https://i.imgur.com/RDYsqPx.png)? Is it displaying the contents of your JSON array properly?

Comment: yes i get this output : `<h3>Cindy</h3><br>0000000000
map.js:53 <h3>Gaia</h3><br>1111111111`

Comment: Something else is the issue, then. When I rewrite my example to [fit with your use case](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-rosalind-jb9ld7?file=/index.html) (external JSON file, fetching, etc), I have no problems with opening the popups. What is your leaflet.js version? If it's not the latest, can you upgrade it, and see if the problem will be solved?